# get data showing in console but not in array laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

here is my app.js looks like

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    msg: 'Update new Post:',
    content:'', 
    posts:[],
    },

    ready:function(){
        this.created();
    },

    created(){
         axios.get('http://{mydomain}/home/post')
             .then(response=>{
                 console.log(response);//show if success
                 this.posts=respoonse.data;// putting posts into array 
             })
             .catch(function (error) {
                 console.log(error.response);
             });

    },
```

my view page looks like

```
 @{{posts}}
```

and my controller looks like

```
 public function getPost(){
        $posts_json = DB::table('posts')
    ->leftJoin('users','users.id','posts.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('profiles','profiles.user_id','posts.user_id')
        ->get();

        return $posts_json;
    }
```

its showing nothing in the array but data showing in console

```
{data: Array(9), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

Comment: You are using response in console.log and respoonse the next line

Comment: Yeah it's my mistake found it .. now it's working fine . Thanks you .. silly me